# Swift: Random number arrays inside images and variables with a for loop

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, for-loop

I am creating a game in which, *depending on the number of 'swipes' chosen to do, (let's say 3), 3 different patterns show on the screen, one by one.* I am working on developing the first pattern.

So I have this:

```
if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 3 {
        swipeArray = Array<UInt32>(count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)
        for i in 0 ..< 3 {
            swipeArray[i] = arc4random_uniform(84)}
    }
```

As far as I am aware, *this code creates an array with three UInts* which **can be accessed by doing swipeArray[0], swipeArray[1], and swipeArray[2]**. My first question is *how long will this swipeArray stay the same*? Until the close the view? *Should I have a 'refresh button' when the user loses - and if so, how would I make one?*

Then I have a **property observer**. You will notice the **for loop**, which I am using to keep code *concise*. I understand that I could do something like `x++` somewhere in here so that it will go through each one.

```
var playBegin: Bool = false{
    didSet {
        if playBegin == true {
            println("\(playBegin)")
            var swipes = Menu()
            if (swipes.no_of_swipes) == 3 {
                for i in 0 ..< 3 {
                    patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern\(swipeArray[x])")
                    //rest of code
                }
            }
}
```

The pattern image comes from a **set of 84 images** named like `pattern7` and `pattern56`. My second question is, *how could I code the for loop to go through each swipeArray[x]*.

*Thank you in advance,*

**Will**

Comment: Are you looking for `for i in 0 ..< 3 {
                    patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern\(swipeArray[i])")
                    //rest of code
                }`

Comment: @MidhunMP Sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Answer for your second question. The above code iterates through that swipeArray 3 times

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes I know, but x in the swipe array needs to change each time.

Comment: What you mean by x ? The value ? or the length of array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how long will this swipeArray stay the same?

This is a bit too open ended.  It’ll stay the same until you assign a new value to it, either from this same bit of code or a different part.  Only you can know when that will be, by looking at your code.

Since you express an interest in keeping the code concise, here’s a couple of code tips.

You might think about writing your first snippet’s loop like this:

```
swipeArray = (0..<swipes.no_of_swipes).map { _ in
    arc4random_uniform(84)
}
```

This combines creating a new array and populating the values.  By the way, just in case you don’t realize, there’s no guarantee this array won’t contain the same value twice.

It’s also probably better to make `swipeArray` of type `[Int]` rather than `[UInt32]`, and to convert the result of `arc4random` to an `Int` straight away:

```
Int(arc4random_uniform(84))
```

Otherwise the `UInt32`s will probably be a pain to work with.

For your second for loop, you can do this:

```
for i in swipeArray {
    patternRoom.image = UIImage(named: "pattern\(i)")
    // rest of code
}
```

When writing Swift, usually (but not always), when you find yourself using `array[x]` there’s a better more expressive way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. When I put Int(arc4random_uniform(84)) I get the error that I can't 'find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments'. Thank you

Comment: Most likely because you haven’t changed the type of `swipeArray` to be of type `[Int]` instead of `[UInt32]` – i.e. the problem is not converting the result of `arc4random` to an `Int`, it’s with assigning an array of `Int`s to an type that is an array of `UInt32`s.

Comment: Ah OK. So how should I edit this `swipeArray = Array<UInt32>(count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)` Thanks

Comment: You don’t.  Delete that line.  All it is doing is assigning a new array (filled with three zeroes) to `swipeArray`, which you are going to replace on the very next line with yet another array.  That line is not declaring the `swipeArray` _variable_ (i.e. `var swipeArray`).  Is it a member variable or a global?  Find that part, and change it.

Comment: 1) open up a new playground 2) paste this into it: `let no_of_swipes = 3; var swipeArray: [Int]; swipeArray = (0..<no_of_swipes).map { _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(84)) }; println(swipeArray)` 3) see it works 4) figure out how your code differs and why that is breaking it.

Comment: Ok That's working really well. Thank you. Do you have any idea how I can stop the same pattern coming up twice?

Comment: You should mark this question as answered (if it was) and ask a fresh question really.  But if you ask that particular one it’ll get marked as a duplicate since it’s [been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+random+repeat)